# count only the first record of an entry as 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have been searching but could not get a result for what am looking for. maybe I have not managed to phrase well, please all pardon.

here is a sample data let's I have this policy table

```
policy_Id   name    deleted invoice number  amount
2341       jeffa       0       po02345      £10.00
2342       jeffa       0       po02345      £0.00
2343       jeffa       0       po02345      £5.00
6348       kross       0       po84762      £2.00
4723       mad         0       po67452      £3.00
```

the result i am expecting will look like this

```
policy_Id   name    deleted invoice number  amount  Count_policy Added
2341        jeffa      0       po02345       £10.00     1
2341        jeffa      0       po02345       £0.00      0
2341        jeffa      0       po02345       £5.00      0
6348        kross      0       po84762       £2.00      1
4723        mad        0       po67452       £3.00      1
```

i want to be able to do this with MS sql query. for invoice no. po2345, there are 3 entries for amount column. I want to count 1 for the first and zeros for the remaining 2.

Thanks all

Comment: Do you have a table definition of all related tables? And also the query you tried already?

Comment: okay I will get that across today, a much more look alike of the data am working on. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT policy_Id, name, deleted, invoice_number, amount, CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY policy_Id ORDER BY someId) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Count_Policy
FROM your_table
ORDER BY policy_Id
```

With `ROW_NUMBER()` you can count the row number after a "behind the scenes" grouping and sorting.

In the `ORDER BY` I used `someId`, you should specify there the field that gives your current order, which is not clear from your code. That order will define which one of the records sharing `policy_Id` will have `Count_policy = 1`.